# Why does a tuple union expect `never` as `.includes()` argument?

Tags: typescript

```js
type Word = "foo" | "bar" | "baz";

const schema = {
  foo: ["foo"] as const,
  bar: ["bar"] as const,
  baX: ["bar", "baz"] as const,
};

const testFn = (schemaKey: keyof typeof schema, word: Word) => {
  const array = schema[schemaKey]
  array.includes(word);
//               ^
// TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.    
//  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
}
```

[**Playground link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6g9gJwCZQLxQEQDM5w1AH0wCMBDBfIjMgLwwG4AoRgYzgDsBnYKTlgCwgBbUmigBvRlCg44ALigBtbLgwBdKKU5Q2XYABopUMggXKT6zdt3dD0sgA0z1chn0lSdDVp0dbjAF8mVj8eYAhuADF2MQAKPkERAGkIEAUAa1S4LChQSGzeAWFSdwB3RCQFeGQASjQAPgkjGx5yBFIQMQTixW7k1LUjNo6AOgBLdhYAGwBXJAjY8tqmIKA)

Why does this happen? It seems just silly to me... or is there something I'm missing? How do I reasonably work around this? Do I just assert to never, or are there hidden caveats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's take a look at some of the types. We have

```
array: readonly ["foo"] | readonly ["bar"] | readonly ["bar", "baz"]
```

Now, the `include` method on a `T[]` takes an argument of type `T`, i.e. an argument of the correct type for the list. This means that, in Typescript, it's not well-typed to ask whether a string is an element of an array of integers, as that sort of code is likely a mistake to begin with.

Now, we don't have an array. We have a union. You can only call a method on a union if the method is applicable to *all* of the union options.

`["foo"]` has a method `include` which takes a `"foo"` as argument (that is, the type whose only inhabitant is the literal string `"foo"`. Likewise, `["bar"]` has a method `include` which takes a `"bar"` as argument, and `["bar", "baz"]` has a `include` which takes an element of the type `"bar" | "baz"` as argument.

But we don't know which of these we have. We could have any of them. So our `include` has to take something that would be valid for all three of these. That is, our `include` must take an argument of type

```
"foo" & "bar" & "baz"
```

So we can pass any string which is equal to all three of the above strings. I don't know of any such string, and neither does the Typescript compiler, so it rightly says that that type is uninhabited, i.e. `never`. There is no *type-safe* way to call `include`.

You can `any`-cast your way around it, like you can everything in Typescript. But the smarter technique is to maintain type safety. See, Typescript is inferring a type *too specific* for your `array` variable, a common problem when you start dealing with literal types. But it seems you *want* the type to be

```
array : readonly Word[]
```

which, as it happens, is a perfectly valid supertype of of the type I indicated at the top of this post. We can simply use an explicit type declaration to make the code work

```
const array: readonly Word[] = schema[schemaKey]
```

Note that this is *not* a cast. We're not telling the type system "I know better than you, hush". `readonly Word[]` is a perfectly valid supertype of the literal union Typescript was inferring. This code is still typechecked and typesafe. We just had to give the compiler a little hint as to our intentions.