# Typescript fails to narrow discriminated union

Tags: typescript, types, discriminated-union, type-narrowing

Let's say I have two types: `X` and `Y`

```js
type X = 'foo';
type Y = 'bar';
```

And I have a following discriminated union:

```js
type DiscriminatedUnion =
    | {
        type: 'X',
        fn: (arg: X) => void;
        arg: X;
    }
    | {
        type: 'Y',
        fn: (arg: Y) => void;
        arg: Y;
    }
```

So it's clear, that object of type `DiscriminatedUnion` will have both `fn` and `arg` of same type: either `X`, or `Y`. Why does TS fails to compile following function?

```js
function acceptsUnion(union: DiscriminatedUnion): void {
    // it's obvious, that both fn and arg would be either X, or Y, but strictly the same type
    const {fn, arg} = union;
    fn(arg); // TS Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a tuple union expect \`never\` as \`.includes()\` argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68106505/why-does-a-tuple-union-expect-never-as-includes-argument)

Comment: Here https://catchts.com/react-props you can find a way to handle it

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68106505/why-does-a-tuple-union-expect-never-as-includes-argument), nevertheless I decided to provide a solution.

There is another way, I did not mention in my blog.

You can overload your function in the union and add extra generic.

```js
type DiscriminatedUnion =
    | {
        type: 'X',
        fn: (<T extends X|Y>(arg: T) => void) & (<T extends X>(arg: T) => void);
        arg: X;
    }
    | {
        type: 'Y',
        fn: (<T extends X|Y>(arg: T) => void) & (<T extends Y>(arg: T) => void);
        arg: Y;
    }
```